# Find ownership for a given temp table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a good way to find out which user and process owns a given user created temp table in tempdb?

Comment: this is a good question

Comment: This is old now but https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/dude-who-owns-that-temp-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query, courtesy of Paul White:

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME(CONVERT(INTEGER, OBJECTPROPERTYEX(t.OBJECT_ID, 'OwnerId')))
FROM tempdb.sys.tables AS t
WHERE t.name LIKE N'#TempTableName%';
```

Comment: While it looks both promising and delightful if true, I could not get this to work. I get `sa` running from tempdb, regardless of how I created the #table, and NULL otherwise.

Comment: Hmm I'm seeing that as well (though in SQL Server 2016). Did you try in 2014 or older?...I'm curious if this changed over time. Either way, I'm going to revisit and see if I can get working in later versions of SQL.